# I can't link button in .xib to method in .m file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

(I've just learn objective-c for a short time. I still don't know how to generate UI elements through writting code now.)

There is one button in .xib.
There is one method in .m.

I want to link these two things by ctrl-click "Touch up Inside" and "File's owner". However, no method shows up when I move the mouse cursor onto File's Owner's icon.

The situation is like this:
http://www.badongo.com/pic/13577347

the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ChangeViewController : UIViewController 
{

}

-(IBAction)goToSecondView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)goToCalculatorView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)test:(id)sender;
@end
```

the .m file:

```
#import "ChangeViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
@implementation ChangeViewController
-(IBAction)goToSecondView:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES]; 
    [secondViewController release];
}

-(IBAction)goToCalculatorView:(id)sender
{
    CalculatorViewController *calculatorViewController =[[CalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalculatorViewController" bundle:nil];       
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:calculatorViewController animated:YES];
    [calculatorViewController release];
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Display the code of .h file... How are you defining the method?

Comment: I've updated  my question with code, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also make sure your File's Owner class is of type '`ChangeViewController`'. For doing so, select the File's Owner, Go to the inspector (press command + 4), and set its class to '`ChangeViewController`' if not already set.

Comment: Thanks. But, is it OK if I change it from "RootViewController" to "ChangeViewController"?

Comment: The File's Owner is nothing but the object which would load the xib file. Why would you load a xib file whose File's owner is lets say viewControllerA by a viewControllerB? So if you have prepared a view controller.h and .m files, with outlets and IBActions and want to create a xib file that would use these outlets and IBActions, you need to set the Class of File's Owner in xib file, so that it recognizes the outlets and IBAction methods.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm the below points:

1) Have you defined method in .h file?

2) Have you defined method with -(IBAction)

Hope you will be able to bind it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on file owner's than you will see list of methods you have defined. Connect than method to you control by drag and drop. Once you will attach that method to your button, all the events that can be fired will be displayed. Select TouchUpInside...

[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCZhDOgVFNA)